# That house is my friend's

Tags: possessives

How to say correct:

> That house is my friend's
>
> That house is of my friend
>
> That house is of my friend's

Answer (score 3):

The most natural way of saying it is:

> That is my friend's house.

If you really want to be using *that house*, then the following is okay:

> That house is my friend's (house).

(The extra *house* at the end is optional; I'd avoid it, personally, but it's not wrong or unnatural in my experience.)

Finally, one other option:

> That is the house of my friend.

That comes across as stilted/archaic. Most of the time, genitive *-'s* is more natural and idiomatic than genitive *of* when talking about actual possession or close association with a person. If there's a concept or inanimate objects, you might use genitive *of*:

> Hey, look! There's a house of mirrors!

Comment: So, these variants are wrong? |That house is of my friend| |That house is of my friend's|

Comment: "That house is of my friend" is, I believe, grammatical - but utterly unnatural. It would mark the speaker as not only not native, but clearly not fluent. "That house is of my friend's" is ungrammatical, as it is using two genitive markers.

Comment: Should you want (intentionally, of course) to sound even more stilted/archaic, you could say "that house is the house of a friend of mine)

Comment: @Rompey, oh, yes, it sounds so deliciously... I really like it:)

Answer (score 0):

All these are correct:

That house is my friend's house.
That house is my friend's.
That house is his.

Comment: Are there any variants with "of"? LIke, |That house is of my friend|

|That house is of my friend's|?

Comment: Not really, in modern idiomatic English.